# Typescript keyof type annotation

Tags: typescript

I am learning Typescript and came across a bit of code that looks something like this (note that this is pulled from a larger project and I had to change some names so let me know if more info is required).

```
export class SpecialProduct extends Product {
   public warehouseName: keyof IWarehouse = 'warehouse.name';

   //Remaining code where warehouseName is used
}


export type IWarehouse = IStorage & {
  'warehouse.name': string;
  'warehouse.poBox': string;
}
```

My question is with regard to the line `public warehouseName: keyof IWarehouse = 'warehouse.name';`

`warehouseName`'s type is specified as `keyof IWarehouse` and then set to a string `'warehouse.name'`.  What reason may there be to use `keyof` instead of something like `public warehouseName: string = 'warehouse.name'`?

Comment: Please consider making the code a [mre] that doesn't have any issues unrelated to your question; right now `Product` and `IStorage` are not defined and you're not asking about them, so you might want to remove them.  It's also hard for me to imagine an authoritative answer to the question; I *presume* the author of `SpecialProduct` doesn't want to allow `warehouseName` to be set to `"someRandomString"`, and instead wants to limit it to the keys of `IWarehouse`.  Maybe someone will look up an `IWarehouse` object with `warehouseName` as a key?  But how could I answer for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `keyof IWarehouse` for the type `warehouseName` ensures that it only has values which are keys of IWarehouse. *(In your case: 'warehouse.name' and 'warehouse.poBox')*.

This makes the code more type-safe, because as soon as you assign another non-key value of `IWarehouse` to `warehouseName` it results in a type error.

> What reason may there be to use keyof instead of something like public warehouseName: string = 'warehouse.name'?

Declaring `warehouseName` as a string would allow any string value even if it is not a valid IWarehouse key, this can lead to potential runtime errors and reduces the maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

`keyof` in Typescript used to define type of variable equivalent to property type of an Object.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
function printInfo(person: Person, property: keyof Person) {
  console.log(`Property ${property}: "${person[property]}"`);
}
let person = {
  name: "Masum",
  age: 26
};
printInfo(person, "name"); // Printing Property name: "Masum"
```

`keyof Person` here creates a union type of "name" and "age".Either `Person` is string or number. Other type like bool will not be allowed

In your `type IWarehouse` contain both property as string. So `public warehouseName` will always be type string